# Not able to override asp.net menu control css to show up menu in UP direction

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, menu

I have asp.net menu control at the bottom of the page, I have an issue which i am not able to resolve if menu control has sub menus then they hide if screen is small, I tried to change the css of Menu control to show menus in UP Direction rather than Down direction, this didn't work for me. Now i am looking for a simple solution Hover even i want to scroll down to bottom of page so that all menus will be visible.

[Example](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm)

I tried different things like

```
   var $elem = $('#Container');
   $(".popout level1 static selected").hover(function () {
        $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
        return false;
    });
```

So far i am not able to trap the even with any of the class, I am not the jquery or CSS kind of guy  i am sure i am doing some thing wrong. I would appreciate help in this regards.

I either want menu to show up in UP direction of scroll down to bottom of page so that all menus are visible.

**Possible Solution**

Change following two lines of code in ddMenuSlider.js file

Change `top` to `bottom` and make `top:''`

```
$subul.css({bottom:this.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? this._dimensions.h+"px" : 0}) 

$mainmenu.find("ul").css({ display: 'none', visibility: 'visible', top:''})
```

Comment: The tinyurl is not good for us.

Comment: As they are, you probably only move them to open up

Comment: @Aristos, How can i do that

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is on your `ul` that opens and hold the popup menou to **remove the** `top` and use the `bottom` with the height of your menu that is the **24px** (actually is 26, but place 24 or 25 to looks line connected).

You have the style inline, so inline change is `style="bottom:24px;"` (and the rest of the style)

[image]
<sub>(source: [planethost.gr](http://www.planethost.gr/so/MenuUp9923.jpg))</sub>

That way the menu will open up.

Comment: Problem is that this style is generate by asp.net menu control at rendering asp.net page & i am not able to overwrite it. I tried to change it using jQuery but it doesnt work as i am not able to trap the right event for this `display: none; position: absolute; top: 28px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; width: 232px;` It works when i dot it using FireBug but not in the actual page

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker I do not know to answer to that with out research, can you please research and find a way to change that ?

Comment: Even `#Menu1:submenu:11
{
    display: none; position: absolute; bottom:24px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; width: 186px;
} `

doesn't work either

Comment: @Aristtos, Problem is that it only works when i try to change it using firebug, in actual this inline property is generated by asp.net menu control & i am not able to fine a way to overwrite it. I tried with jQuery which is not working either

Comment: try putting **!important**.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this one:

just find this in the `ddsmoothmenu.js` :

```
`$subul.css({top:this.istopheader`
   //--------^^^-------------------change this to bottom
```

Try changing this and see if this helps.

Comment: Even commenting this line wont make any difference

Comment: changing top to bottom changes the property but also keep top:100% which actually make no difference

Comment: I finally made it to work by changes  the `.js`  file `$subul.css({bottom:this.istopheader && setting.orientation!='v'? this._dimensions.h+"px" : 0}) 

$mainmenu.find("ul").css({ display: 'none', visibility: 'visible', top:''}) `